# How can I repair the degraded surface of a concrete slab and wall?

Tags: repair, concrete

I've never worked with concrete. Is there an easy way for a concrete newbie to repair this wall?

- OR-

How do I fix it?

[image: wall]

Here is another view, further back.

[image]

**===================  Found these in a store ===============================**

Will any of these products work for my issue?
[image: product1]
[image: product2]

Comment: Can you add another pic from another angle? I can’t quite tell what I’m looking at. Also, what is the scope of the problem...just a chip or something much larger?

Comment: @Lee Sam I've added another picture.  It is a concrete garage floor.  Inside is fine.  It is chipping and ugly at the driveways edge.

Comment: So you're asking about surface repair, as opposed to cracking or settling?

Comment: @isherwood  Yes.  There are cracks and holes in the concrete.  Is it as simple (DIY)  as buying some pre-mix and a trowel?  Or more complicated that I need a mason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vinyl cement patch is what you're probably after. It's designed to bond well and handle impacts and movement in thin applications much better than concrete or mortar. It can be feathered to a thin edge.

Mix per the instructions on the package and apply with a wide putty knife or trowel.

Be aware that you won't have good results spanning from one concrete object to another. There's almost certainly seasonal movement between the two that will tear the patch apart. Use a control joint where necessary.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "Use a control joint"

Comment: https://www.cement.org/learn/concrete-technology/concrete-construction/contraction-control-joints-in-concrete-flatwork

Comment: Are any of the products I posted what you were thinking of in your reply?

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic on this network. Read the labels and decide for yourself. Obviously some of those match what I suggested.

Comment: I was only asking if those products fit the "Vinyl cement patch is what you're probably after" recommendation given.

Comment: Not having access to their labels, nor a photographic memory, I can't be sure. My hunch is that they're both fine.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the quickrete product is a powder you must mix with water, not pre-mixed.
Either product would be appropriate for patching those chipped areas, but in truth this is probably the most mild concrete damage I've ever seen anyone want to correct.